# "assign_public_ip: no" still creating public IPs: Ansible and EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have defined `assign_public_ip: no` to my ec2 creation task:

```
- name: Basic provisioning of EC2 instance
      ec2:
        assign_public_ip: no
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        image: "{{ standard_ami }}"
        instance_type: "{{ free_instance }}"
        key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
        count: 3
        state: present
        group_id: "{{ secgroup_id }}"
        wait: no
        #delete_on_termination: yes

        instance_tags:
          Name: Dawny33Template
      register: ec2
```

Yet, the spawned instances are being assigned public IP’s:

```
TASK [Add new instance to host group] ******************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={u'kernel': None, u'root_device_type': u'ebs', u'private_dns_name': u'ip-172-31-45-61.us-west-2.compute.internal', u'public_ip': u'35.167.242.55', u'private_ip': u'172.31.45.61', u'id': u'i-0b2f186f2ea822a61', u'ebs_optimized': False, u'state': u'pending', u'virtualization_type': u'hvm', u'root_device_name': u'/dev/xvda', u'ramdisk': None, u'block_device_mapping': {u'/dev/xvda': {u'status': u'attaching', u'delete_on_termination': True, u'volume_id': u'vol-07e905319086716c9'}}, u'key_name': u'Dawny33Ansible', u'image_id': u'ami-f173cc91', u'tenancy': u'default', u'groups': {u'sg-eda31a95': u'POC'}, u'public_dns_name': u'ec2-35-167-242-55.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', u'state_code': 0, u'tags': {u'Name': u'Dawny33Template'}, u'placement': u'us-west-2b', u'ami_launch_index': u'2', u'dns_name': u'ec2-35-167-242-55.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', u'region': u'us-west-2', u'launch_time': u'2017-01-31T06:25:38.000Z', u'instance_type': u't2.micro', u'architecture': u'x86_64', u'hypervisor': u'xen'})
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that I was launching the slave instances in a public VPC. So, the public IPs are being assigned by default.

So, if the public IPs are not wanted, then one needs to launch the instances in a private subnet of a VPC. For example, below is an example task for provisioning EC2 instances in a private subnet:

```
- name: Basic provisioning of EC2 instance
  ec2:
    assign_public_ip: no
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    image: "{{image_instance }}"
    instance_type: "{{ free_instance }}"
    key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
    count: 3
    state: present
    group_id: "{{ secgroup_id }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ private_subnet_id }}"
    wait: no
    instance_tags:
      Name: {{ template_name }}
  #delete_on_termination: yes
  register: ec2
```

Answer (score 2):

The "assign_public_ip" field is a bool value.
[here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_lc.py#L290)

Somebody did fix this in the ansible-module-core library but change wasn't reflected.
[here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/583/files#diff-74356b4e26d3b0a785194e2aad7fe7f4R264)

Comment: [ec2](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/5f89fc4a689fed6d60a79ba23fae6860706cb82d/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2.py#L1561) module has it as boolean and `no` is like `false` in YAML. I guess, this is not the case.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Yeah. I did try with `false` too. Didn't work :(